# Json.NET:Can not deserialize JSON, if the base class of the specified type is "PropertyChangedBase"

Tags: c#, json.net

The following are my test codes：

```
public class Department : Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase
{
    public System.Guid DepartmentId { get; set; }

    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string jsonString = "{DepartmentName:123}";
    Department department = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Department>(jsonString);
        System.Console.WriteLine(department.DepartmentName);
        System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The result is that the value of "DepartmentName" is null as its initial value.

Are there any solutions？

Comment: what if you add `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the properties?

Comment: Thank you！You are right. It works if add the [JsonProperty] attribute to the properties.
But it will need to add the [JsonProperty] attribute to all properties of the class.

Comment: Yes you will need to add that attribute to each property

Comment: I posted as an answer. If it solved your issue please accept the answer. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `[JsonProperty]` attribute to each property.